# PHP. Проверка на существование переменной.

Tags: php, opencart

Работая с opencart встретил такой кусок кода:

```
if($moneymaker2_footer_links_enabled){
     // Какое-то действие
}
```

При этом если переменная $moneymaker2_footer_links_enabled не объявлена, php выдает ошибку о том что данная переменная не найдена, для чего тогда нужна эта проверка если $moneymaker2_footer_links_enabled не предполагает true или false, т.е. я уверен что в этом куске кода идет проверка именно существования переменной, но при её отсутствии появляется ошибка.

Это какой-то старый способ проверки существования переменной, ведь isset с этим справляется?

Comment: Дайте весь кусок кода, и там может быть не только true/false, такая проверка сработает если переменная содержит хоть какие-то данные.

Comment: Там просто вывод переменной в div-е, `<div class="moneymaker2_title" ><?php echo $moneymaker2_footer_links_enabled; ?></div>`

Comment: Судя по всему moneymaker2, это какой-то модуль или шаблон, может это просто косяк разработчика, либо где-то еще при определенном условии объявляется данная переменная...Судя по названию отвечает за какие-то ссылки в футере.

Comment: Посмотрите что будет если загуглить название переменной: https://www.google.com/search?q=%24moneymaker2_footer_links_enabled

Comment: http://joxi.ru/xAeYVvwiY8aNkA меня это удивило, в описании сайта какие-то логи. Видимо, на тех сайтах также используется moneymaker2 и выдает ошибку.

Comment: Именно, видимо просто баг, если Вы не знаете что это, и оно не влияет на правильную работу, а судя из Google, таки влияет на описание страниц, лучше поищите его (везде), в коде и удалите, либо закомментируйте.

Comment: Но дело в том, что там (в шаблоне) таких проверок очень много, так проверяется переменных 30, если не больше.

Comment: Я имел ввиду конкретно эту...

Comment: Сделайте дамп подозрительных переменных, и посмотрите что в них...

Answer (score 1):

В поисковике у вас не логи а уведомления о том что переменная не определена.

Переменная с таким названием не входит в набор стандартных для Opencart. Судя по уведомлению, данная переменная должна передаваться контроллером `footer.php` в представление `footer.tpl`, либо генерироваться прямо там. К сожалению, многие разработчики грешат тем, что работая с opencart (который mvc) частенько прячут часть логики в файлы представления (шаблоны с расширением .tpl).

Сам же файл `footer.tpl`, судя по тому же уведомлению, читается из кеша (`system/storage/modification`). Туда обычно сохраняются изменённые расширениями стандартные файлы шаблонов. Из этого можно предположить, что был какой-то экстеншн ocMod, который перезаписал файл шаблона футера, занося в него свои изменения. Судя по названию переменной, она отвечает за вывод блока ссылок, на соц.сети или ещё куда-нибудь.

Если таковое расширение использовалось вами и было отключено/удалено, то от него мог остаться кешированный файл шаблона футера - `footer.tpl`. В таком случае вам необходимо обновить кеши. Делается это из админки, меню "модификаторы" (кнопки в правом верхнем углу).

Если вы не уверены в происхождении переменной, просто дополните конструкцию **if** проверкой **isset**:

```
if(isset($moneymaker2_footer_links_enabled)){
    // Какое-то действие
}
```

Нужно понимать, что если расширение всё-таки установлено и активировано, любое стирание кешей будет приводить к перезаписи файла `footer.tpl` и исчезновению правок.